# How to extract a large tar file

Tags: perl, tar

I need to extract a 25GB tar file using a Perl script that works like this shell command.

```
tar xvf tarFile.tar file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt ...
```

This is what I have tried.

#### Solution 1. Gives out of memory error.

```perl
use Archive::Tar;

my $tarPath    = 'path/to/tarArchive';

my $tar        = Archive::Tar->new($tarPath); # Out of memory
```

#### Solution 2. Gives out of memory error.

```perl
use Archive::Tar;

my $tarPath    = 'path/to/tarArchive';

my $tar        = Archive::Tar->iter($tarPath, 1, { filter => qr/file1\.txt$/ } );

while ( my $f = $tar->() ) {

    print $f->name, "\n";  # Out of memory
}
```

Could you please help me understand what is wrong?

Comment: It seems you're not the only one with this problem. https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=104087

Answer (score 3):

It seems Archive::Tar works by loading everything in memory. From their docs...

> Isn't Archive::Tar heavier on memory than /bin/tar?
>
> Yes it is, see previous answer. Since "Compress::Zlib" and therefore
>           "IO::Zlib" doesn't support "seek" on their filehandles, there is
>           little choice but to read the archive into memory. This is ok if you
>           want to do in-memory manipulation of the archive.

Note that this limitation may not exist anymore, Compress::Zlib now offers gzseek, but IO::Zlib doesn't yet support it.

It goes on to offer some work arounds.

> If you just want to extract, use the "extract_archive" class method
>           instead. It will optimize and write to disk immediately.

That would be `my @extracted_files = Archive::Tar->extract_archive($file)` then you can work with the files on disk.

> Another option is to use the "iter" class method to iterate over the
>           files in the tarball without reading them all in memory at once.

Looks like you already tried this.

---

Another option is to use [Archive::Tar::Wrapper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Tar::Wrapper) which is, you guessed it, a wrapper around `tar`. According to its docs, it never stores anything in memory.

> Archive::Tar::Wrapper is an API wrapper around the 'tar' command line utility. ***It never stores anything in memory***, but works on temporary directory structures on disk instead. It provides a mapping between the logical paths in the tarball and the 'real' files in the temporary directory on disk.

Answer (score -1):

why cant you execute it using backtick (`)

`tar -xvf source destiantion`

Comment: Try to extract a small sized tar file and see whether its working with your code . If it is not working then . you dont have enough memory to keep the unzipped files .